# The most recent rows in for each type/agent in Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have a table with lots of data. This table is written by some scripts. It works like a "check in", where each agent is checking in in some period of time. It looks like below.

| id | agent | status | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | tom | ok | 2023-03-16 12:27:03 |
| 2 | jeff | degraded | 2023-08-31 00:01:13 |
| 100 | tom | ok | 2023-10-03 12:00:00 |
| 101 | jeff | ok | 2023-10-03 11:59:00 |

I'd like to pick the most fresh line per each agent. So in above example I'd like to get row 100 and 101.

I tried many different ways but still not getting what I want. I use MySQL, so distinct is not for me this time.
On one hand there is a way to make distinct values per agent, like below:

```
AgentCheckin.objects.all().values('agent').distinct()
```

But it's just a name of an agent. I need to get whole query set with all the information.
I think this kind of use case should be somehow common in multiple web apps, but looking here is SO, it's not that common with ultimate answer.

Model:

```
class AgentCheckin(models.Model):
    agent = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    agent_version = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    log = models.TextField(blank=True)
    host = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Please share your models.

Comment: Model added to the main post. It's fairly simple, but still I'm trying my best and no solution found.

Comment: What database do you use?

Comment: It's MySQL 5.7 still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that will work with any database is:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

AgentCheckin.objects.filter(
    ~Exists(
        AgentCheckin.objects.filter(
            agent=OuterRef('agent'), timestamp__gt=OuterRef('timestamp')
        )
    )
)
```

we thus filter out `AgentCheckin`s if there is an `AgentCheckin` with the same `agent`, and a more recent timestamp.

Comment: Excellent, this works perfect. Thanks a lot! I need to dive into Exists part here, it's new to me.